# How can i get 64 bits of the fractional part of the square root of a number in java?

Tags: java

How can i get 64 bits of the fractional part of the square root of a number in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find a library that calculates the value to 64 fractional bits, or study the algorithms and write it yourself. A `double` **does not store** 64 fractional bits; it stores 64 **total** bits. Only 53 of those are used to represent the fraction ("mantissa", technically speaking; a number like 1.xxxxxxx in binary, except the 1 is always 1, so there is no need to record it), 12 are used for an exponent (so that the `double` can represent very large numbers as well as numbers that are very close to zero), and 1 is used for a sign (so that it can represent negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If you need 64-bits, you can use double precision to get up to 53-bits (note for values 1 or more, you will get less fractional precision) and then use BigDecimal and successive approximation to get more bits of precision.

Is this homework?  I can't see a practical use for this.

Comment: this is not homework. I'm trying to generate this to use them in implementing SHA512.